# Can't get handshake through de-authentication when penetration testing WiFi

Tags: penetration-test, wifi

I am trying to pentest the security of my wireless network. It is configured as a WPA2 with pre-shared-key. I start capturing traffic in order to get a handshake and when I make a de-auth, the router changes the channel, so I can't get the handshake. Any workaround? Any idea? It is a Sercomm VOX 2.5 customized by Vodafone.

Comment: de-auth packets are are part of normal AP to wireless client communications, so the AP can't just change channel on each de-auth packet. Try to send a small number of de-auth packets, not jamming the network with many of them.

Comment: I was using a script that does several de-authentications. When I did it by hand I got the handshake without problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In general, de-auth packets are are part of normal AP to wireless client communications, so the AP can't just change channel on each de-auth packet.

Try to send a limited number of de-auth packets, if you're close enough to the AP, a packet or two will do the job nicely.

**Edit**:
From comments feedback, the problem was because of using scripts to automate several de-authentications, and it was solved by sending packets manually.